# Filter a result set to include only the top 99.9% of values in Splunk, preferably without a subquery

Tags: splunk

I am querying the access logs to a service.  I want to build a scatter plot where the X axis is the total number of requests in that hour, and the Y axis is how many times a particular request (category) was made in that hour.  To do this, my output needs to be:

```
requestDetails, per_hour, count
```

Easy enough. I use a query like:

```
<base query setting requestDetails>
| bucket _time span=1h
| stats count by _time, requestDetails
| eventstats sum(count) as per_hour by _time
| table requestDetails, per_hour, count
```

The challenge I am running in to is, there are very infrequent items that just add clutter to the chart.  I don't care about every request, just the common ones.  So I'd like to **filter it so that only the requestDetails that make up 99.9% of traffic are included**.

In theory, I could do this with a sub-query:

```
<base query>
[ search <base query>
| stats count by requestDetails
| sort -count
| eventstats sum(count) as total
| eval percent=count/total*100
| accum percent as percentile
| where percentile <= 99.9
| field requestDetails
]
| bucket _time span=1h
| stats count by _time, requestDetails
| eventstats sum(count) as per_hour by _time
| table requestDetails, per_hour, count
```

The problem is, it's expensive to do it this way, since I have to extract the data twice.  And it doesn't exactly give me what I want, since it is a pre-filter, so the value of `per_hour` is missing the values for those filtered rows.

It seems to me I should be able to accomplish this with a single-pass through the data using `eventstats` or `streamstats`.  But I'm drawing a blank on how to emulate the `accum` command because there are so many rows for a given `requestDetails`, and what I need is to only count any given `requestDetails` once.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do as a post-filter, without using a subquery?  If so, what would it look like?

Comment: what does the underlying data look like? I think there's a way to do this with `head`, but would need some sample data to try it out on :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is possible to do this using a single pass through the data:

```
<base query>
| bucket _time span=1h
| stats count by _time, requestDetails
| eventstats sum(count) as per_hour by _time
| eventstats sum(count) as per_request by requestDetails
| eventstats sum(count) as total
| sort -per_request, +requestDetails
| streamstats sum(count) as count_til_now
| eval percentile = count_til_now / total * 100
| eventstats max(percentile) as max_percentile by requestDetails
| where max_percentile <= 99.9
| table requestDetails, per_hour, count
```

The key is the sort.  We first organize them from most common `requestDetails` to least common.  The other sort terms are to avoid overlap in the event of a tie.

We also have to take some `eventstats`, such as the total number of times a particular `requestDetails` was seen in the whole dataset, and the total number of requests.

The fun part is to use `streamstats` to create a running total, and use that to calculate the percentile.

But then in order to build our filter we do another `eventstats` to calculate what is the maximum percentile of a particular `requestDetails`.

All that is left is to filter where the max_percentile is below the threshold, and output the data needed for the visualization.